# JMSCorrelationID prefixed with ID:

Tags: java, jms

I have some code which is doing this:

```
String transactionId = incoming.getJMSCorrelationID();
```

when I used ActiveMQ for testing I was able to send messages through and pick up this value without problem. However, when I am connected to Websphere the value comes through prefixed with 'ID:' I have no idea why this should be the case - the middleware people tell me that my code must be adding it - which it's not.

It's a simple case for me to remove it, but I want to know why this prefix appears - any ideas anyone?

Comment: WebSphere Application Server or WebSphere MQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the middleware people are wrong:

> #### JMSMessageID from MQMD MessageID
>
> All messages sent from JMS have unique message identifiers assigned by WebSphere® MQ. The value assigned is returned in the MQMD messageId field after the MQPUT call, and is passed back to the application in the JMSMessageID field. The WebSphere MQ messageId is a 24-byte binary value, whereas the JMSMessageID is a string. The JMSMessageID is composed of the binary messageId value converted to a sequence of 48 hexadecimal characters, **prefixed with the characters ID:**. JMS provides a hint that can be set to disable the production of message identifiers. This hint is ignored, and a unique identifier is assigned in all cases. Any value that is set into the JMSMessageId field before a send() is overwritten.

From: [Mapping JMS header fields at send() or publish()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fuj25470_.htm).

Also I remember noticing that prefix while working with JMS-WebsphereMQ bridge. But actually - why do you care? <del>This is a `String` id, the specification doesn't say anything about its structure, except that it has to be unique.</del>

UPDATE: Actually, as mentioned by *@skaffman*, the `ID:` prefix is required by [JMS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jms-2_0-edr-spec/index.html):

> #### 3.4.3. JMSMessageID
>
> All `JMSMessageID` values must start with the prefix ‘`ID:`’. Uniqueness of
>   message ID values across different providers is not required.

This means that WebsphereMQ bridge is adding `ID:` prefix only to be compliant with JMS spec. And, as also noted by *@skaffman*, ActiveMQ is not compliant with it...

Comment: +1 The JMS spec also requires that system-generated message identifiers are prefixed with `ID:`. Looks like ActiveMQ has got it wrong (again).

Comment: I think this answer is correct. I work many time with WebSphere MQ, MessageId and CorrelationId start both with prefix 'ID:'

Comment: @Tomasz. Thanks for your response and the link. I need to know what's going on with this value as it gets returned in an acknowledgement message and they don't want the ID: prefix on it. The doc you have quoted refers to JMSMessageID - do you know if that's going to be the same for JMSCorrelationID? Apologies if this is a daft question - JMS is not a hot topic of mine.

Comment: Here's a link to the docs [JMSMessage](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/jms/JMSMessage.html) (see `getJMSMessageID`), which explicitly states that `All JMSMessageID values must start with the prefix 'ID:'.`

Comment: According to this, there was a bug in WMQ 7, which did not allow the selector `ID:hexval` for JMSCorrelationID, but that should be fixed: [Bugreport](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ37281)

Comment: @Tomasz and skaffman. Thanks for your efforts - I've put this to my middleware team who will probably come back and tell me I am still wrong - they are always right ;) At least now I don't feel like I' going mad.